# Benefits of destructuring assignments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

More and more often I come across code making use of the ES2015 introduced destructuring assignment and even more often I find it very hard to understand what the author is doing. I can see that destructuring can be very useful in some cases but I have the impression that it is often introducing unnecessary code complexity.

E.g. the [Nested object and array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring) example on MDN is using this line do destructure a nested array:

```
var { title: englishTitle, translations: [{ title: localeTitle }] } = metadata;
```

Where is the advantage over something like this, that looks a lot more readable to me:

```
var englishTitle = metadata.title,
    localeTitle  = metadata.translations[0].title;
```

---

What problems are being solved by destructuring assignments?

When to use them and when not to?

Comment: Your two pieces of code aren't equivalent. `localeTitle` is the title property of the first object in `translations` array.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I edited the question.

Comment: With simpler cases it saves keystrokes and is still readable `const { foo, bar } = this.props;` vs `const foo = this.props.foo; const bar = this.props.bar;`

Comment: As with any language feature, it can be misused/abused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The benefit is that you don't need to repeat the destructured expression. Granted, in your example it hardly makes a difference, as you've already got it neatly in that `metadata` variable.

But if it is a very complex expression, or something else, you could save an extra variable. For example, compare this function

```
function example(metadata) {
    var englishTitle = metadata.title,
        localeTitle  = metadata.translations[0].title;
    …; // use englishTitle and localeTitle
}
```

to

```
function example({title: englishTitle, translations: [{title: localeTitle}]}) {
    …; // use englishTitle and localeTitle
}
```

and it becomes more obvious how declarative it is.

As it is true for every syntactic sugar: apply it only where it sweetens your code.

Comment: is this really better than just making the function take more parameters and then passing each parameter individually? I agree that it looks more expressive compared to just passing metadata, but I am so used to defining functions and then just passing in the right parts at the calling end.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet Yes, passing objects around is still simpler than passing individual values around separately and maintaining their connection manually.